# How to find the matching records from 2 files in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have two files which contains email_ids.
1. Test1.txt
2. Test2.txt

Test1.txt contents are:

`abc@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
mns@gmail.com`

Test2.txt Contents are:

`jpg@gmail.com
joy@yahoo.com
abc@gmail.com
pet@yahoo.com`

Here abc@gmail.com is common id between Test1.txt and Test2.txt. I want to find out such Id's from these 2 files and insert them into one file.

Please suggest. I just need the ID's which are common in between these two files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]; next} $1 in A' file1 file2 > file.new
```

--edit: added explanation --

```
awk '           
  NR==FNR {               # When the first file is being read (only then are FNR and NR equal)
    A[$1]                 # create an (associative) element in array A with the first field as the index 
    next                  # start reading the next record (line)
  }              
  $1 in A                 # while reading the second file, if field 1 is present in array A then print the record (line) 
' file1 file2 > file.new  # first read file1 as the first file and then file2 as the second file and write the output to a 3rd file.
```

Comment: can you explain a little your awk statement? It's not that obvious to me :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `grep` too:

```
grep -Fwf Test1.txt Test2.txt
```

```
$ head t*
==> t1 <==
abc@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
mns@gmail.com

==> t2 <==
jpg@gmail.com
joy@yahoo.com
abc@gmail.com
pet@yahoo.com
```

```
$ grep -Fwf t1 t2
abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Yes that works too, but it is more sensitive to spurious spacing. If you put one space in front of 'abc@gmail.com' in the first file, for example, (like is the case in the sample file) then it will not find a match (whereas the other way around it will).

Comment: @Scrutinizer Yep thats true. `:)`